# Struggling to add subtitles to a video using FFMPEG and C#

Tags: c#, windows, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add subtitles to my videos, 100% with code using FFMPEG and C#.

But I'm getting the following error:

> ffmpeg version 2024-02-04-git-7375a6ca7b-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
> libavutil      58. 36.101 / 58. 36.101
> libavcodec     60. 38.100 / 60. 38.100
> libavformat    60. 20.100 / 60. 20.100
> libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
> libavfilter     9. 17.100 /  9. 17.100
> libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
> libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
> libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\XXXX\bin\Debug\net8.0\ce31c8ab-4b53-44e8-9e25-d02ba5466144\output.mp4':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : isom
> minor_version   : 512
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
> encoder         : Lavf60.20.100
> Duration: 00:03:18.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 101 kb/s
> Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1024x1792, 26 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
> encoder         : Lavc60.38.100 libx264
> Stream #0:10x2: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 74 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : SoundHandler
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
> [Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000001a87404e3c0] Unable to parse option value "UsersGamersourcereposXXXXbinDebugnet8.0ce31c8ab-4b53-44e8-9e25-d02ba5466144output.srt" as image size
> Error applying option 'original_size' to filter 'subtitles': Invalid argument
> [vost#0:0/libx264 @ 000001a874064a40] Error initializing a simple filtergraph
> Error opening output file C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\XXXX\bin\Debug\net8.0\ce31c8ab-4b53-44e8-9e25-d02ba5466144\videoWithSubtitles.mp4.
> Error opening output files: Invalid argument

It seems to be something related to paths, but I have tried EVERYTHING in my knowledge to fix this, still no luck... spent the majority of the day on it, no luck... so StackOverflow here I come!

My code:

```
   public static async Task AddSubtitlesToVideoAsync(string videoPath, string subtitlesPath, string outputPath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(videoPath) && File.Exists(subtitlesPath))
        {
            //string subtitlesPathForwardSlashes = subtitlesPath.Replace("\\", "/");
            //string ffmpegCommand = $"-i \"{videoPath}\" -filter_complex \"subtitles='{subtitlesPathForwardSlashes}'\" \"{outputPath}\"";
            //string ffmpegCommand = $"-i \"{videoPath}\" -vf subtitles={subtitlesPathForwardSlashes} \"{outputPath}\"";
            //string ffmpegCommand = $"-i \"{videoPath}\" -vf subtitles=\"{subtitlesPath}\" \"{outputPath}\"";
            string subtitlesPathEscaped = subtitlesPath.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
            string ffmpegCommand = $"-i \"{videoPath}\" -vf subtitles=\"{subtitlesPathEscaped}\" \"{outputPath}\"";


            //output    -i C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\XXXX\bin\Debug\net8.0\d745a08d-b932-47ac-a81c-45e9483590a7\output.mp4 -vf subtitles="C:/Users/Gamer/source/repos/XXXX/bin/Debug/net8.0/d745a08d-b932-47ac-a81c-45e9483590a7/generatedSubtitles.srt" C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\XXXX\bin\Debug\net8.0\d745a08d-b932-47ac-a81c-45e9483590a7\videoWithSubtitles.mp4
            await ExecuteSubtitleCommandAsync(ffmpegCommand);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Files can't be found.");
        }
    }

    public static async Task ExecuteSubtitleCommandAsync(string arguments)
    {
        string ffmpegExecutablePath = ffmpegRoot;
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ffmpegExecutablePath, arguments)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };

        using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
        {
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // Enable the Exited event.
            process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg process exited with code {process.ExitCode}.");
            };

            try
            {
                process.Start();
                // Asynchronously read the standard output and standard error of the process
                var outputTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
                var errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();
                // Wait for both asynchronous tasks to complete
                await Task.WhenAll(outputTask, errorTask);

                var output = await outputTask;
                var error = await errorTask;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FFmpeg error: " + error);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FFmpeg process completed successfully.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Wait for the process to exit if it hasn't already.
                if (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```